# PUT on Java through HTTP

Tags: java, http, put

I have a put annotation in java

```
@PUT 
@Path("create-user") 
public Response createCor(@QueryParam("cor_id") String cor_id, 
@QueryParam("bill") String bill 
) 
{ 
if (StringHelper.isEmptyOrWhitespace(cor_id) || 
StringHelper.isEmptyOrWhitespace(bill)){ 
and so on...
```

When I make a request to
http://[ip-address]:[port]/api/example/create-user?cor_id=1&bill=12/   
I get an error. An example of an error in the screenshot 
[image]

Comment: This is not a PUT but a GET as your url suggest. Choose, PUT or GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default, you are using GET method to request to that url 
you can only test the other methods by using some tools like postman 
use postman to make requests:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mkCT.png

Comment: Thank you very much))
I do it